# jQuery, Canvas, SVG or HTML5 click circles dynamically into DIV - best approach for getting started

Tags: jquery, svg, html5-canvas

I want to click in a DIV element and place circles... what is the best approach for this.  I would want to place possible hundreds of small circles, about 5 pixel diameter, sometimes overlapping.  Then when I have all the circles I want I will need to save this pattern.

Can anyone suggest a good place to start on this?

FYI... I am on a Linux server LAMP stack.

------------------ OK, added my code after initial suggestions.

the code works except that the dynamically created circles are hidden??? any ideas(fixed see below)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    div{
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: #0033FF;
    }

    /*]]>*/
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var X = 0, Y = 0;
    $('.clickInHere').live('mousemove', function(e){
                $('h1').html(e.pageX + ' - ' +e.pageY);
                X = e.pageX;
                Y = e.pageY;
                });
    $('.clickInHere').live('click', function(e){
                $('#circlesHere').append('<circle cx="' + X + '" cy="' + Y + '" r="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none"/>'); // NOTE: THIS DIDN'T WORK PROPERLY... SEE BOTTOM
                });
    // ]]>
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="clickInHere"></div>
    <div class="circleContainer" style="background-color: #eee;">
       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="circlesHere"></svg>
    </div>
    <h1></h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

----- update ----

Ok so the dynamically created circles were not showing because I was creating them incorrectly... here was the fix

```
            var obj = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
            obj.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", X);
            obj.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", Y);
            obj.setAttributeNS(null, "r",  Radius);
            obj.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", strokeColor);
            obj.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", 1);
            obj.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "white");
            $("svg")[0].appendChild(obj);
```

I put this into a function and it worked perfectly.

Comment: sounds like you want to use an HTML5 Canvas? What have you tried so far, and what problems are you running into?

Comment: Will, I ended up trying to combine SVG with jquery (see added code above) but the dynamically created circles are hidden.  Any idea on the fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely SVG or HTML5 Canvas are the options here. The decission between both of them could come from what you need to do with the circles.

While in SVG is easier to reference the elements you draw and manipulate them as objects inside your program, Canvas is extremely fast at drawing/redrawing the entire portrait.

If you are going to save the patterns I supose that you'll just save the position of the circle's centers and their radius, redrawing them when needed. For such a scenery I'd opt for canvas (it will render the whole image faster), however if you are expecting to use some "drag and drop" effect on the circles maybe SVG will be a better option.

If you offer us more info about the use of the elements we could be able to suggest you more accurately the way to go.

Comment: Bardo, thanks for the tips... I ended up trying to combine SVG with jquery (see added code above) but the dynamically created circles are hidden.  Any idea on the fix?

Comment: My SVG is a bit rusty, but I'm not sure you can just add code to the SVG tag and expect it to re-render the image. You'd probably had to include your svg tag into your jquery code and post it to the page each time you want to reload it (If I'm right here it means that you'll need to record all your circles into a single string to post them each time a new one is created).

Comment: Bardo, thanks... I got it figured out, and made some more mods... see above.